# Binding Chart to TableView JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView with data, and would like a PieChart to visualize the data in that table. I can not understand how I am supposed to bind the arraylist from the TableView to the Piechart, as the TableView requires getters and setters, while the piechart requires a PieChart.Data observable list.

This is my current code, the elements are designed with Scene Builder

```
@FXML
private TableView<Record> tableView;



static ObservableList<Record> dataen
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Record("January", 100),
                new Record("February", 200));




public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Month.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fieldMonth"));
    Value.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fieldValue"));
    tableView.setItems(dataen);

}

}
```

Comment: [Oracle sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jtable-barchart.htm#BABDCCJC) using a listener on the table.

Comment: I've seen this, but it doesn't at all help me in my example. I am using the scene builder, and the problem is that I can not set the observablelist "dataen" to the PieChart..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make a listener on your TableView items list (dataen) or just use the same list for both.  Here they use the same list.  You could change your list to be of type `<PieChart.Data>` instead of `<Record>`, otherwise use a listener.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;

public class ChangePie extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
                new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10),
                new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
                new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");

        TableView tv = new TableView(pieChartData);
        tv.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn("Name");
        tc1.setPrefWidth(100);
        tc1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
        tc1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

        TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn("Data");
        tc2.setPrefWidth(100);
        tc2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("pieValue"));
        tc2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));

        tv.getColumns().addAll(tc1,tc2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(chart,tv));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what do I do when I use scenebuilder? 
I had "Month.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fieldMonth"));
Value.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fieldValue"));

tableView.setItems(dataen);"

But when I change from Record to PieChart data, the tableview doesnt get any data..

Comment: Woho, thank you. Found it out, had to change from :     Month.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fieldMonth")); to "name" instead of "fieldMonth", how so?

Comment: PieChart.Data already has names for it's fields, name and pieValue.  If you're just using those fields then you don't need a separate class for table data.

Comment: Thank you, so is pieValue and pieName always standard for pie chart ?